# Limit of a given sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $A_1=1$ and $A_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{1+A_n}$ for every natural $n$. Define $B_n=1+A_n$.

I should find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n$.

Please help!

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: i think you need an explicit formula for $a_n$

Answer (score 1):

Hints: show that the limit $A$ of $(A_n)_{n\geq 1}$ actually exists.  (Try the Monotone Convergence Theorem)

Once you've done this, taking the limit on both sides of $A_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+A_n}$ you should find that $A=\frac{1}{1+A}$.  Solve this to find $A$.

Finally, use the fact that in general $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{(a_n+b_n)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{a_n}+\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{b_n}$ to find the limit of $(B_n)_{n\geq 1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed point is a solution of $x=1/(1+x)$, i.e $A=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}
 $

Further, if $a_{n}=\frac{p}{q}$ then $a_{n+1}=\frac{q}{p+q}$, i.e $a_{n}=\frac{f_{n}}{f_{n+1}}$, where $f_{n}$ are Fibonacci numbers, 1,1,2,3,5...

So, limit of $a_{n}$ is $A=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ and limit of $b_{n}$ =  $B=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ = *Golden ratio*.

Comment: Yes, but argument with a Fibonacci sequence is a proof. $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1}
 $$ is defined recurently $f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_{n}$  So, $ a_{n}=f_{n}/f_{n+1} $ by induction

Comment: that is true, thank you.

Comment: More generally method for answer is from Banach fixed-point theorem. So, a mapping $F: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] $: $x\rightarrow \frac{1}{1+x}$ is a contraction, 
$$|x-x'|<|\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1+x'}|=\frac{|x-x'|}{(1+x)(1+x')} $$
i.e. there exist a unique fixed point and this is an attractor. And unique fixed point is 1/Goldenratio